# How to fix field name is undefined error?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript code to sort strings but I get error a.k is undefined

```
var dataset = [{
  "field1": "dfg34r",
  "field2": "sdfsd"
}, {
  "field1": "d3f32dg",
  "field2": "fgjfgj"

}, {
  "field1": "fdbhjjts",
  "field2": "hswer"
}, {
  "field1": "dfg4r",
  "field2": "ghje"
}, {
  "field1": "fgsdfwe",
  "field2": "dhfke"
}];

function sort_col(evt){
  var k = evt.target.innerText; //k = clicked field name field1 or field2

    dataset.sort(function (a, b) {      

      var nameA = a.k.toUpperCase(); // error here a.k is undefined
      var nameB = b.k.toUpperCase(); 


      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      }

      if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      }

      // names must be equal
      return 0;   

    }); 

  }
```

if I removed `toUpperCase` the code work normally so how I can fix this error and be able to convert string to upper case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `bracket notation` at this context instead of a dot notation,

```
var nameA = a[k]toUpperCase(); 
var nameB = b[k]toUpperCase();
```

If you use `dot notation`, then property look up over objects `a` and `b` will happen for the property `k`, not the value which resides inside that.

Comment: yes thanks, it sould be a[k].toUpperCase();

Answer (score 0):

I think modifying the code like below should solve the undefined problem.

```
  function sort_col(evt){
   var k = evt.target.innerText; //k = clicked field name field1 or field2

  dataset.sort(function (a, b) {
  var nameA = "";
  var nameB = "";     
  if(k=="field1"){
  nameA = a.field1.toUpperCase(); // error here a.k is undefined
  nameB = b.field1.toUpperCase();
   }  else{
  nameA = a.field2.toUpperCase(); // error here a.k is undefined
  nameB = b.field2.toUpperCase();
 }



  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;   

});
```

}

It is giving undefined for a.k as it will not be able to replace the value of k dynamically during the a.k.toUpperCase evaluation.